# how to cmpare the values of Arraylists

Tags: java

how can we compare the values of two array lists for example :

```
    ArrayList a = new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add("1");
    a.add("2");
    a.add("3");

    ArrayList b = new ArrayList<String>();
    b.add("3");
    b.add("2");
    b.add("1");
    System.out.println(areEqual(a, b));
```

should print true , because all values of a are in b.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's right in the API. I don't understand why people don't make use of this resource.

Comment: Can you have duplicate values? If not, do the counts of each value have to match as well?

Comment: @Matti -- gets much more complicated if we start talking about duplicates. Need a better definition of "equality" then.

Comment: @Kal: His definition of "equality" is exactly what I'm trying to find out here.

Comment: Come on @Mohammed , it would at least have been nice to leave a comment about this whole definition of equality thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if ( a.containsAll(b) && (a.size() == b.size() ) )
```

EDIT: If a contains more elements than b, containsAll will still return true , so if you want to test for absolute equality, then a size comparison is necessary.

EDIT #2: This assumes that the a and b contains unique entries. If there were duplicates, like @Robin and @Matti have referred to, it would be much more complicated depending on the OPs definition of equality.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't help since it doesn't take the number of duplicates of each one into account.  It does not confirm this definition of equality.  To test for this form of equality (where order doesn't matter) then you will have to manually parse both lists and track all the duplicates.  Size of the overall list is meaningless.

Comment: I was basing my comment on the assumption that duplicates were acceptable, since it is using an ArrayList.  The OP has not defined this so I will retract my downvote.  This answer should be edited to include the assumption that the list is in fact a Set.

Answer (score 10):

The list interface contains this function `boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c)` which appears to do what you want.
[http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Answer (score 2):

inspired by an answer above, this would solve the problem better:

```
if ( a.containsAll(b) && b.containsAll(a) && (a.size() == b.size() ) )
```

This should also be a working equals() case even if the lists contain duplicates.

EDIT: via the suggestion of Jon7, here is an improved version that checks the same unique elements:

```
Set set1 = new HashSet();
set1.addAll(a)
Set set2 = new HashSet();
set2.addAll(b);
if ( set1.containsAll(set2) && set2.containsAll(set1) && (set1.size() == set2.size() )) {
    System.out.println("Lists are equal");
}
```

Comment: This is also a good thought if the OP wants to test if all values of a are in b and all values of b are in a. However it doesn't handle the case that list a contains 5 of an element and list b contains 6 instances of it. In that case, the lists are "equal" but this method would return false. At this point, we are guessing at what the OP is really asking.

Comment: Calling an unnecessary containsAll, rather: `if (a.size() == b.size() && a.containsAll(b))`